# I've object {name: 'John', 'surname': 'Johnson', 'age': '20'}

Tags: javascript, function, object

Please tell me, I need to write a function that writes the corresponding values
into the variables name, surname and age. 
How can this be implemented?

```
let user = {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Johnson',
    age: '20',
};


let{name, surname, age} = user;
document.write(name + ' ' + surname + ' ' + age);
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on what you're trying to do? Are you trying to create a function that can create these User type objects from paramaters?

Comment: a function that can overwrite existing object value @Milton

Answer (score 0):

Ummm

```
function writeUser(user){
    document.write(user.name + " " + user.surname + " " +user.age)
}
```

?

Comment: its not a function

Comment: Like this?(I edited the code) I don't really understand what you are trying to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this is something in the lines of what you're looking for:

```
const user = {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Johnson',
    age: '20',
};

function updateUser(user) {
    user.name = "New name";
    user.surname = "New surname";
    user.age = "New age";
}

updateUser(user);
const { name, surname, age } = user;
document.write(name + ' ' + surname + ' ' + age);
```

By adding an other parameter to this function you might make it more useful, like this:

```
function updateUser(user, overrides) {
    Object.assign(user, overrides);
}

updateUser(user, { age: '30', name: 'New name' });
```

This would change the age and name but leave the surname, but it modifies the input user which isn't really a good pattern, better to return a new object instead:

```
function updateUser(user, overrides) {
    return Object.assign({}, user, overrides); // First assign user to the empty object, then assign the overrides to that new object
}
```